# When I Mouse Hover Into An Image That Image Displays Into Another Div Or Table Colums?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want to an image gallery. On the left side all thumbnails are there. When i mouse hover into thumbnail, the full image will be displayed into the left side div or table. So please tell me the correct code or plugin or anything.

The image gallery exactly looks http://www.rakindia.com/products.aspx?subcat=SW-0000702

Please friends i am trying from 2 days i can't find any plugin and code. Please help me
(i AM TRYING FOR MULTIPLE IMAGES)

Comment: Does my answer not suit your needs?

Comment: This question does not make any sense at all "On the left side all thumbnails are there. When i mouse hover into thumbnail, the full image will be displayed into the left side"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it inline to save overhead. You do not need a plugin for such a simple request, not even jQuery, but pure javascript.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/8U3C7/

Swap the `src` image on mouse down

```
<img src="myFirstImage.jpg" onmousedown="document.swap.src='myFirstImage.jpg';" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for giving me the good code. And one more is i don't need to use the individual images. I am using the asp.net code. And how i added the multiple images. for Suppose in .net i am using this code like this <img src='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' onmousedown="document.swap.src='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>';" runat="server" />

 But its not working. Thank u very much

Comment: If you provide a link to your website I could investigate as to what the issue is.

Comment: OK I am waiting for you reply sir. Thank u very much.

Comment: What is the address for your website?

Comment: It is under the control of client. He give a just reference website
http://www.rakindia.com/products.aspx?subcat=SW-0000702 (RakIndia.com)

Comment: The gallery on that website is working ok, I can not see a problem with it.

Comment: Thank u very much sir, I did it with multiple images. Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't explain yourself clearly, this is a [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/7cpPe/) for you. Next time try describe yourself better in English, and show people at least what you have tried not to ask for a simple solution.
Uses just plain js and css.

```
 function updateIMG(e) {
        document.getElementById("preview").src = e;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.rakindia.com/products.aspx?subcat=SW-0000702
see this url. I want exactly like this.
Thank u

Comment: Hi, Thanks for giving me the good code. 
And one more is i don't need to use the individual images. I am using the asp.net code. And how i added the multiple images.
for Suppose in .net i am using this code like this
<img src='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' onmouseover="updateIMG(this.src);" runat="server" />

But its not working.

Thank u very much

Answer (score -1):

try this plugin it's quite similar to against your requirement: [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-2.html)